# VB.NET Shifting row up/down in SORTED datatable

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to create functions to shift up or down row in datagridview, which is fed from datatable dtProc. It would be easy on an unbound datagridview, but I am trying to achieve it with datasource = dtProc. The problem is, that I **sort** the dtProc accordint to RowNo (a correct order). The function bellow works, but only ONCE. Second time it shifts rows in the *original* position, not the desired rows, which moved up by 1 row. The indexes are correct, but the unsorted dtRows (on which the operation is performed) has different order then displayed, sorted dtRows.

```
Private Sub ShiftUp()
    If Me.dgwNew.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then            ' if selection exists
        Dim selIdx As Int16 = Me.dgwNew.SelectedRows(0).Index      ' selected index
        Dim secIdx As Int16 = Me.dgwNew.SelectedRows(0).Index - 1  ' second index
        MsgBox("selIdx=" & selIdx & "     secIdx=" & secIdx)       ' test feedback
        dtProc.DefaultView.Sort = ("RowNo ASC")         ' trying to keep sorted order
        dtProc.Rows(selIdx)("RowNo") = secIdx + 1       ' swap selected index with second
        dtProc.Rows(secIdx)("RowNo") = selIdx + 1       ' swap second index with selected
        Call RefreshDgw()
        Me.dgwNew.ClearSelection()                      ' clear datagridview selection
        Me.dgwNew.CurrentCell = Me.dgwNew.Rows(secIdx).Cells(0)
        Me.dgwNew.Rows(secIdx).Selected = True          ' set selection on secondary row
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshDgw()
    dtProc.DefaultView.Sort = ("RowNo ASC")
    Me.dgwNew.DataSource = dtProc.DefaultView.ToTable
End Sub
```

Is there a trick to make it work?

**EDIT - FINAL SOLUTION:**

I was unable to work with DataView either, the problem persisted. So I had to add an extra function, which gets row index in DataTable according to a row index in DataView.

```
Private Function GetDataTableRowID(rowIdx)
    Dim RetVal As Int16
    For ir = 0 To dtProc.Rows.Count - 1 
        If rowIdx + 1 = dtProc.Rows(ir)("RowNo") Then
            RetVal = ir
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

Then I modified the two lines, where I set indexes as follows:

```
        Dim selIdx As Int16 = Me.dgwNew.SelectedRows(0).Index      ' selected DataView index
        Dim secIdx As Int16 = Me.dgwNew.SelectedRows(0).Index - 1  ' second DataView index

        Dim selIdx2 As Int16 = GetDataTableRowID(selIdx)      ' selected DataTable index
        Dim secIdx2 As Int16 = GetDataTableRowID(secIdx)      ' second DataTable index

        dtProc.Rows(selIdx2)("RowNo") = secIdx + 1       ' swap selected index with second
        dtProc.Rows(secIdx2)("RowNo") = selIdx + 1       ' swap second index with selected
```

Comment: a) that wont compile under Option Strict b) datatable rows are different than datagridvioew rows c) if you want to change the order "in the datatable" then change the values of that RowNum cell and leave the DGV out of it.

Comment: @Plutonix a) It does compile under Option Strict. b) I agree, but I don't see any mismatch c) That's what I am trying to do, the DGV code you see there only ensures, that the correct row is selected after a change in order has been performed. Because when you move a row up, you want the selection to be moved up with the row, i.e. so that you can continue with moving the row further up.

Comment: I have a complete working example here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Move-rows-updown-and-987fe786

Comment: Thank you very much Karen, I will remember your comment and will look into your code and article next time I'll be implementing this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add an Integer column to your DataTable called Sequence
2. Set your table DefaultView.Sort to Sequence
3. Create a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sd1cd0a(v=vs.110).aspx) that initially sorts your data on RowNo
4. Iterate the rows in the view assigning Sequence to row index
5. Bind your table to your DataGridView
6. Change the Sequence value in the table rows to move rows up/down

Comment: I was unable to achieve the result even with extra sorting ad DataView definitions, however I will mark this as an answer, as it more or less led me to the solution. And after all, it may have been some stupid mistake of mine, which prevented this exact solution to work.